# Amended pushed commit - how to recover sync without force?

Tags: git, push, git-amend

I amended a pushed commit. Now can't push to git repo.

I do not want to push with `-f` key because it will make a lot of problems to other people.

Currently I see only one solution:

1. git clone
2. write changed files over from a backup copy
3. make a new commit
4. push it

Do you know a better way?

Comment: Reset to the previous commit before the push, pull from upstream. That should put you back to before you amended.

Comment: @tripleee: What is "upstream" in this case?

Comment: The place you already pushed to.  Basically, pull back down what you already pushed, then redo as a separate commit instead of an amend.

Answer (score 0):

Amending a commit generates a *new commit*.  If you have already pushed the (previous version of the) commit to a remote repository, you cannot push the new commit without `-f` because that would alter the existing history of the remote.  A key promise that git makes is that a given commit -- and the history leading up to that commit -- cannot be modified without generating a new commit id.

Your options are:

- Just use `git push -f` and let people know, or
- Create a new commit after the existing one and push that.

Some workflows (for example, those involving [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) or [GitHub](http://github.com/) pull requests) rely on forced pushes as a regular operation (e.g., for updating an existing pull request).  Adopting a workflow like this can give you more opportunities for fixing things "after the fact".